# Using .css property in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

`Code 1`

```
jQuery("ul#leftmenuacc").find("span.leftmenutextspan")[0].css('color', 'red');
```

The above code doesn't work, so I had to do it another way [ below mentioned ]

`Code 2`

```
jQuery("ul#leftmenuacc").find('span.leftmenutextspan').each(function(index){ if(index ==0) jQuery(this).css('color', 'red') });
```

I am confused here as why didn't the `Code 1` works? I read the documentation on `.css` from [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/), but couldn't find what I am missing.

Is there an elegant way to do it? Because currently I am iterating through a lot of DOM Items for no use.

Comment: if you exactly copy-pasted your code, in the first line, you didn't actually closed your quote at `ul#leftmenuacc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing `$(selector)[0]` you will get HTMLElement, which hasn't got `css` function. You may wrap it with jQuery like: `$($(selector)[0])`, but better solution is to use `:eq(0)` or `:first` selector:

```
jQuery("ul#leftmenuacc").find("span.leftmenutextspan:eq(0)").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining and nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("ul#leftmenuacc").find("span.leftmenutextspan:first").css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

in Code 1 you are missing doublequotes (") after `ul#leftmenuacc`

and I'd do it like this

```
$("span.leftmenutextspan:first", "ul#leftmenuacc").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Liked your approach too.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers provide working solutions. If performance is not entirely unimportant to you, the following should be considered as well:

1. **Refrain from using `:eq` (or `:first`, as suggested in some of the other answers) *selectors* whenever you can.**

   Usually, jQuery uses the browser's native `querySelectorAll()` DOM traversal method, which is considerably faster than jQuery parsing the DOM tree on its own.

   Since `:eq` and `:first` are jQuery-specific, `querySelectorAll()` cannot be used – thus, jQuery has to resort to using its own, much slower, traversal engine instead.

   The recommended alternative for this scenario is the use of jQuery's `filter()` or `first()` (which, afair, internally maps to `filter()`) methods:

   ```
   jQuery("ul#leftmenuacc").find("span.leftmenutextspan").first().css('color', 'red');
   ```

   Quote [jQuery's own documentation on `:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

   > Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.
   >
   > To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first").

   How much speed do you gain? Well, `.first()` is around 10 times as fast as `:first` in standard scenarios.
2. The use of `find()` seems unnecessary in your example and slows your code for the same reason as mentioned above. This would be the better alternative:

   ```
   jQuery("ul#leftmenuacc span.leftmenutextspan").first().css('color', 'red');
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Performance is not really an concern for me for now. But I will definitely keep this in mind.